# ASP GridView Format Field as Currency

Tags: asp.net, gridview, string-formatting

I have tried these two different techniques to try and get the value to show as currency but neither of them are working

They show like this `1234.12` instead of this `£1,234.12`

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Price2" HeaderText="Price2" DataFormatString="{0:c}" 
SortExpression="WebShop" />

<asp:BoundField DataField="Price1" HeaderText="Price1" DataFormatString="{0:##,0.00}" 
SortExpression="Price1" HtmlEncode="False" 
HtmlEncodeFormatString="False" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer:

because my gridview was populating data from a database i.e. with a SQL Query

I had to cast the column as money and it worked!

E.g.

```
SELECT 
cast([price1] as money) as 'price1',
cast([price2] as money) as 'price2' 
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll depend on the culture settings on the server. 
For example, if the culture setting on the server is "en-US", then you'll see a dollar sign.
For showing pound you should use `Pounds (GBP)`.

If you want to set it for all files use this in you web.config

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB"/>
```

Else for a particular file use

```
UICulture="en-GB" Culture="en-GB"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but they aren't showing any currency symbol currently